# Change location "Download" folder from CMD - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, command-line, windows-8.1, symbolic-link

I'm trying to change the location of the Windows download folder. I want to do from the CMD and not from "right click - Properties - Location - Find Target". I already tried with the symlink (mklink), but when I download something, the download will both folders, the original and the new. Thx!!!

Comment: why do you not want to use the GUI?

Comment: I want to do it through a script, adding to already i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location you are searching for is stored in Registry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}`.
As already mentioned in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460275/get-the-windows-download-folders-path-download-shell-folder-in-a-batch-file) you could use such a snippet:

```
Reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" /d "C:\Users\YourName\Downloads"
:: Optional:
Reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" /d "C:\Users\YourName\Downloads"
```